# javascript debug tool:firebug, chrome javascript control panel, visual studio for javascript

Tags: javascript

As I know, there are some options

```
firefox firebug
chrome javascript control panel
visual studio
```

What is the best javascript debug tool?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them. They're development and testing tools after all, and you should be testing in and developing for as many browsers and on as many platforms as you can.

Personally, I like the WebKit developer tools in Safari/Chrome, but that's just because those are my preferred browsers, so that's what I'm most used to. But I use all of them, at one time or another, on all the code I write (unless I'm only targeting one specific browser/platform, of course, but that's rare).

I suggest you just start with the developer tools for the browser you're already using. If it gives you trouble, well, then there are the others to choose from. They all work pretty much the same.